How to fold and bend some part of axis with pgfplots?
Like the red mark in the figure below, I'd like to make the y-axis only has -20 -10 10 20, and there's a bending & folding line between -10 and 10. The three gaps have the same height. How can I achieve this effect?

The MWE is following
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width = 7.2cm, height = 7.2cm,
        xmin=0, ymin=-20, xmax=0.72, ymax=20,
        xtick={0,0.24,...,0.72}, ytick={-20,-10,...,20},
        legend columns=0, legend style={
            nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}, column sep=1ex
        },]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


What behaviour do you want for the represented data in the Y-range where the Y-axis line is wiggling? Should some data be plotted as well or is it just a way to "break" the y-axis in a fancy way? If you could update your image with an example of how the data should look like it would be great. I might have a solution.

@mranvick I will insert data via .csv file, and there's no data in the range of y = -10~10, so I want to short this part with zigzig line
